# Is it safe to upgrade to the later minor or patch version of Spartacus, i.e. from 3.2.2 to 3.3.0?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

> I have installed Spartacus 3.2.2 recently. Can I please know is there documentation available to upgrade 3.2.2 to 3.3 ?
> Can I please know if I upgrade to 3.3 will it effect to current development components or pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the later **minor or patch** version of Spartacus **should not introduce any [breaking changes](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/breaking-changes/#avoiding-breaking-changes)** to your application. It's because Spartacus follows the [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) contract.

Sometimes new features introduced in minor versions of Spartacus might require some breaking changes, but in that case such features are not enabled by default. They will appear only when you opt-in to that feature by bumping the [feature level](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/configuring-feature-flags/) in the Spartacus config. You can also opt-in to use the latest SCSS styles, by bumping the styles [feature level variable](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/css-architecture/#style-versioning) in SCSS.

Significant breaking changes can be introduced only in major version. To smooth the migration process for you, Spartacus team provides the migration docs and automated migration tools (aka. *schematics*) that will fix some of the the breaking changes in your code and put code comments in your codebase near the usages of the changed Spartacus API.

For example, here are docs for migration from 2.x to the major version 3.0: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/updating-to-version-3/